# rails 5 - rails generate migration doesn't add migration to folder

Tags: migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm doing `rails generate migration add_fields_to_user name: string` and it responds

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 19915
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20161112145823_add_columns_to_user.rb
```

When I go look in the db migrate folder, that migration is not there.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The table name must be users not user. Can you try this:

```
rails generate migration add_name_to_users name:string
```